# Using iCloud with iPhoto without upgrading to iPhoto 9

Tags: macos, iphone, icloud, photos.app, photo-stream

Is there any way to use iCloud on OS X Lion to share pictures with my iPhone without upgrading to the newest iPhoto? I know the newest iPhoto isn't that expensive but I don't use it for anything at all so I don't want to pay the $16 for an application I don't use.

EDIT: iCloud doesn't work with iPhoto 8 (which is what came on my computer) and the only way I know to use iCloud to share photos is to buy the newest version of iPhoto. Which I don't really want to do so is there another way to share photos or a way to use iPhoto 8 instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27019/photo-stream-access-on-pre-lion-macs), a workaround does exist, but it's ugly.

You'd need to run a virtual machine running Windows (I'm not sure if you could do it with Wine, or if you'd need an actual copy of MS Windows (which is much more expensive than $16). You then download iCloud Control Panel from Apple and install it on your virtual machine. Then, you can use it to send photos to iCloud.

So yes, it can be done. But you're likely better off spending the $16.

Comment: That kinda sucks. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: @Daniel: Then the answer is "No, you can't use iCloud with iPhoto 8."

Comment: The question was if there is a way to share photos via iCloud without upgrading iPhoto.

Comment: Fixed the title to better reflect the question sorry for the confusion